# Is there a name for this theory of truth?

Tags: truth, pragmatism

I am wondering if there is a name for the following theory of truth, which I might call "persuasionism."

> Truth, for an individual, is the set of beliefs that individual would eventually, in the limit, be persuaded of, given unlimited evidence and unlimited time to consider.

This theory may be compared to Charles Sanders Peirce's pragmatist theory of truth:

> Truth is that concordance of an abstract statement with the ideal limit towards which endless investigation would tend to bring scientific belief, which concordance the abstract statement may possess by virtue of the confession of its inaccuracy and one-sidedness, and this confession is an essential ingredient of truth. (Peirce 1901).

Distinguishing "persuasionism" from pragmatism:

- Persuasionism puts the emphasis on what would persuade the individual, not a "community of inquirers."  The rationale is that it does not matter to an individual what might persuade others in the community, unless it also convinces that individual.
- Persuasionism does not restrict the domain of truth to scientific belief; it might be applied as well to philosophical questions such as evaluating the truth of moral claims.

Comment: Which  individual ? [It has been shown that some people won't budge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Prophecy_Fails) even in face of damning evidence. Worst, they get more engaged into their ridiculous belief. This definition does not account for the biases our very imperfect brains struggle with.

Comment: Unlimited evidence, unlimited time to consider, unlimited capacity to process all that (and that's not enough, some cognitive actions can not be performed individually even with unlimited time) would turn this individual into a generic ideal reasoner stripped of any individuality. Or at least it is unclear what "individual" would be left in such a being. There is a reason Peirce had to resort to a community (actually, an unlimited succession of communities) to make this work. Its point is not so much in introducing "others" but in making what your "individual" is supposed to do more palatable.

Comment: armand - when I am selecting my own beliefs, the individual in question would be me; when you are selecting yours, the individual in question would be you.  So it doesn't matter if some third party is irrational.  We do have to idealize the individual's reasoning process somewhat, however, since humans can't biologically have "unlimited time."  Conifold, what could be more palatable to me than the beliefs I myself would arrive at?  Or more palatable to you than the beliefs you would arrive at.

Comment: I'd also like to remark:  a rational person would wish to believe right now, what he himself would in the future believe after considering more evidence.  Because being better informed is preferable for the purpose of forming beliefs over not being so informed.  By the way, the "community of inquirers" suffers from the same problem of irrationality you point to in the individual; groups of people are not rational.

Comment: @causative: so is this a "you have your truth, I have my truth" type of thing? I would not be so worried about the irrationality of a third party, but more about my own, and so should be each individual.

Comment: I imagine that given enough time and evidence, I would be able to identify and fix any irrational reasoning of mine.  Suppose that a community of inquirers would arrive in the limit at conclusion C, and you yourself, fully understanding all evidence and argument of that community, would arrive in the limit at the opposite conclusion ~C.  Which would you name true?  It seems clear you would say ~C is true and C is false; you would trust yourself over the community.  Even if you trusted the community and said C, that would still in the end be your own judgment.

Comment: @armand, however, I do hope that it is not a matter of "you have your truth, I have my truth"; I would hope that in the limit of investigation, we would eventually reach the same conclusions, if either of us are halfway reasonable to begin with.  But this is something else to be argued for, not part of the definition itself.

Comment: One advantage of the "community" idea is that it potentially allows for the possibility of dealing in a distributed way with ever-increasing amounts of information relevant to deciding the truth of certain questions, perhaps too much for any individual to understand or be aware of in total (for ex. a community of mathematicians could collectively decide the truth value of a googolplex distinct mathematical claims). Perhaps one could avoid the need for this if one adopted some sort of transhumanist view where the "individual" in question was something like an AI ever-growing in brainpower?

Comment: @Hypnosifl but we would expect that an individual idealized mind would reach the same conclusion as a community, if it had enough time and evidence.

Comment: Does "idealized mind" include the idea of infinite (or ever-growing) capacity to store information? If not, it seems like even the most idealized mind of fixed finite size would have sets of propositions that were too large for it to ever hold in its mind at once.

Comment: @Hypnosifl yes, an idealized mind would have to have unlimited storage space.  Although this need not apply to working memory, so that the mind remains human - think an ordinary human with unlimited time and access to an infinite library and computer with infinite hard disk on which he may record his observations.

Comment: In this question, do you accept the influence of [anchoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring_(cognitive_bias)) and [Einstellung effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstellung_effect)? Perhaps some people are differentially prone to these effects over the long run. For example, a person who grows bored easily may seek alternative perspectives while someone more consistent may keep old ways. Still, the starting mindset may influence the infinite outcome. You might define *individual* here, so as to include or exclude background experience (nurture) versus genetics (nature).

Comment: Consider also [assimilation and accommodation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaget%27s_theory_of_cognitive_development#Assimilation_and_accommodation), and whether sequence of events changes the outcome.

Comment: @Michael a reasonable person would be able to notice their own cognitive biases and consciously try to correct for them. For example, they could perform statistical analysis of their own judgments in a large variety of contexts, and notice how and why their judgments fail to predict the outcomes, and apply statistical corrections to improve those predictions by making them less biased. Given enough time and effort (and pen and paper) they should be able to reduce the effect of the biases to nil.

Comment: Indeed a scientific approach can help to find and correct biases, but what about general informational structure, such as [linguistic relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity)? My overall point is that prior thoughts anchor and frame later thoughts in a logical way. Moreover, as neural pathways are activated repeatedly, those pathways grow stronger, increasingly minimising alternative perspectives. A complex external algorithm could perhaps avoid this problem with infinite time, but how many people would devise this path? Also, a *Chinese room* could result.

Comment: @Michael Any cognitive bias you can be aware of, including linguistic relativity, is something you can consciously work towards fixing. Additionally I don't require that the investigator creatively think of all these things himself; his job is to be (rationally) persuaded by evidence and arguments presented to him. Although, given enough time, anyone could think of anything just by running through all possibilities. I do not see the "Chinese room" as a problem. It's conscious anyway, and even if it wasn't, a Chinese room built by the investigator is only a tool for him to evaluate and modify.

Comment: I guess my concern at this point is more or less that of @Conifold, that when you extend the mind too far, the result is no longer a person but an algorithm. Whether the resulting Chinese room is conscious, it probably has little resemblance to the mind of the person. Moreover, its beliefs may well differ from those of the person, which seems to be sidestepping the initial premise that the *individual* would be coming to these beliefs rather than an emergent entity. If a person creates a super AI, are its beliefs those of, or an extension of, the person?

Comment: @Michael It is always the person's beliefs being considered. If he builds a Chinese room to think for him, the conclusions of that room do not matter except inasmuch as he accepts them for his own beliefs. Which he might do, on the basis that he knows how it works and is sufficiently confident it would reach the right conclusions. It's no different from relying on a pocket calculator.

Answer (score 1):

You have to identify necessary truths from contingent truths first. For necessary truths, some are fairly intuitive like principle of non-contradiction (PNC), whose truth value cannot be fully justified in any sufficient way no matter how much time passes or how much individual's capability has in this contingent world, even approaching infinite, its value transcends us and thus hidden forever to us even it really exists.

For contingent truths, as most modern philosophers would agree, justified true belief (JTB) is the standard epistemic definition of *knowledge* human can possibly achieve and this seems is what you want to reach. But there're still modern philosophical arguments against justified truth (knowledge) such as [Gettier problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem). The problem lies in how sufficiently a justification can be satisfied for JTB to be really our contingent truth. I guess it doesn't need infinite time or capacity since we can already do sufficiently many experiments within a short time via modern technology, such as the view espoused by scientific [Positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positivism). For me a serious intrinsic issue would be what if the contingent truth itself will change as time passes, such as some geological, biological or even physical laws? Then even given infinite time with infinite individual capacity, one still won't approach a convergent limit of such truth as you wished.

Comment: I don't make any assumptions about how they arrive at their beliefs.  Whether they use PNC or not is up to them; there are some philosophies such as Zen Buddhism that make heavy use of contradictions, and PNC does not hold in fuzzy logic.  Yes, if a truth changes over time due to changing contexts, then perhaps there is no limit of belief for it, and therefore we would not say it is absolutely true or false.  The answer is to fully contextualize the proposition, e.g. not "it is raining" but "at X absolute time and Y absolute location, it is/was/will be raining."

Comment: By the way, the answer to the Gettier problem is to say knowledge is true belief whose justification is also true at every premise and step of reasoning.  But JTB is a separate question from the OP.  I am not trying to define "knowledge" here, only "truth."

Comment: @causative thx for ur feedback! Per ur own quoted definition above "Truth, for an individual, is the set of beliefs", as understood in public language, seems you exactly meant your truth is a kind of belief, and implicitly it needs to be true and justified, otherwise one can believe anything one likes...So I do think JTB (modern knowledge in philosophical context) is exactly the kind of truth OP was interested in.

Comment: I am *defining* truth, so I can't say that truth is justified true beliefs; that would be circular.  Yes, the individual may believe whatever they like.  The idea is that in the limit as they reason more and see more evidence, "whatever they wish to believe" would converge towards a limit, at least for certain beliefs.

Comment: @causative Admittedly public language is not FOL and full of traps to misunderstand in a subtle way. So based on your own definition of truth above (only a set of beliefs, which may not need to be justified and true, personally I'll just use a set of beliefs, no need for a new "truth" concept here), u wish to predict if some belief(s) will emerge as JTB? Well, I think our scientific world seem just such a case, under rational choice theory in economics, this is what positivism claims and hopes to reach. .

Comment: ...However, Karl Popper famously rejected this view, as rational being can only discard false belief, but cannot affirm/posit a true one, not even to say converge to some set of beliefs..

Comment: No, I'm not trying to predict whether beliefs emerge as JTB.  JTB is just not even in the question.  We take an existing reasoning process and ask what would result from that process in the limit, without saying whether we think the results are sufficiently "justified," which itself is a thorny question.  We don't need to use the word "justified" here.  We're just asking what happens with a particular reasoning process (e.g. my own brain's reasoning process) in the limit.

Comment: @causative Ah, now I better understand u further... Well, this seems just Relativism which enjoys popular uprising as one of postmodernism. In some culture nodding one's head means agreeing or appreciating. In our world it's not just isolated individual matters, also one's environment, group, communities, and culture. Something like so called social "intersubjectivity" or community thoughts will get converged to as we're experiencing...It's what modern complex dynamical system theory targets...

Comment: @causative ... the convergent solution set in the long run in dynamical system is called an "attractor" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor). But it's also possible that an unstable "repeller" can form accidently, but not able to be converged to from any close neighborhood, which is quite counterintuitive... And I believe this theory is metaphorically very close to what Wittgenstein called "Form of life" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_of_life_(philosophy))" in his posthumously published works Philosophical Investigations.

Answer (score -1):

> Truth, for an individual, is the set of beliefs that individual would eventually, in the limit, be persuaded of, given unlimited evidence and unlimited time to consider.

This is not a theory of truth. We all know what we all mean by "truth" and this isn't it.

This is not a theory of truth. This is a definition, and it is a redaction of the definition of truth everybody has in mind. This is on a par with so-called Justified True Belief.

So, this "theory" may be a theory of something, but it is not a theory of truth.

I could also define truth as whatever I believe and run with that definition. Many philosophers try to redefine the common notion of truth simply because they want to be able to claim that we know something about the physical world.

A statement is either true or false. Whatever we believe in this respect is irrelevant.

Different people believe different things about the world. We try to arrive at a common view through argument, ideally logical argument based on empirical evidence. Whether we succeed is irrelevant to whether what we believe is true. We have to live with that. We live our lives according to our beliefs. Isn't that good enough? It seems to be working rather well so far.

Another aspect of this question is that being given an unlimited time to consider (the unlimited evidence) is not a method to arrive at the truth. The history of ideas shows how little truth comes out of the lengthy consideration of things. I guess the missing ingredient is called "intelligence", although this in itself doesn't say much. Another way to say it is the ability the solve problems, which is the only definition of intelligence that makes sense. Clearly, humans have such an ability but just as clearly not all in the same amount. The fact is that most people given an infinite time to consider an infinite amount of evidence would still not arrive at the truth.

Comment: Most of the more prolific epistemologists of the last 70 years agree that this whole "Truth (capital T) talk" is *meaningless*. Your appeal to common sense fails since this position is *logically inconsistent*, as Putnam has shown and Tim Buttons beautifully formalised in *The Limits of Realism*. You are the one stating something arbitrarily without further justification here.

Comment: I agree that truth ought to be something universal - which means that with enough time and evidence, any reasonable person ought to come to the same conclusion.  However, even if truth is universal, the problem remains:  some *beliefs* are true and some are false.  Beliefs correspond to physical patterns in the brain.  How do we relate the abstract, universal truth to a physical brain pattern?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking which epistemologists are those? And what do you mean by "capital T"? Are you saying that the more prolific epistemologists of the last 70 years would deny that facts like "my glasses are on my table" can have an absolute truth value? Or do you say that they only deny that *certain* propositions have an absolute truth value?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking 1. "*agree that this whole "Truth (capital T) talk" is meaningless.*" I don't know how that relates to my answer. I can't read your mind. 2. "*Your appeal to common sense fails*" No, it doesn't and you have no argument that it does. The only notion of truth that withstood the test of time is the ordinary, commen-sense notion of truth. 3. "*this position is logically inconsistent, as Putnam has shown and Tim Buttons beautifully formalised in The Limits of Realism.*" So your only argument is to drop names? Am I supposed to search this book to find what exactly is your argument?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking "*You are the one stating something arbitrarily without further justification here.*" Whoa. Arguing from common-sense is to state something arbitrarily?! I'm very nearly speechless. Did you say that the common-sense notion of truth is *meaningless*? This would be one way indeed of arbitrarily dismissing the overwhelming empirical evidence that all human beings abide everyday by it, including in fact yourself. Isn't that true?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking "*this position is logically inconsistent, as Putnam has shown*" Putnam? You mean the bright mind who claimed that Quantum Physics provided a an undeniable counterexample to a logical truth?

Comment: @causative "*How do we relate the abstract, universal truth to a physical brain pattern?*" My answer very clearly doesn't refer to any of what you call "abstract universal truth". The common-sense notion of truth has proved that it works by being used successfully for thousands of years. What matters is what people mean by "truth" and that they think that some beliefs are true and other are not true. Arguing against it is abiding by it.